# How to make Meta Query case sensitive?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, meta-query

I have a meta query similar to:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( 'post_type=article&meta_key=kln_aid&meta_value=' . $aid );
```

where I need `aid` to be case-sensitive. Is that possible via Meta Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how meta_key/_values work. How you store your values is case sensitive.

Example `meta_key = 'foo'` and `meta_value = 'Bar'`

Would return the result you are looking for:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&meta_key=foo&meta_value=Bar' );
```

Would not return the result you are looking for:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&meta_key=foo&meta_value=bar' );
```

However it does appear that your database can be setup as case insinsitive and cause some issues.

> Please note that if your database collation is case insensitive (has with suffix _ci) then update_post_meta and delete_post_meta and get_posts will update/delete/query the meta records with keys that are upper or lower case. However get_post_meta will apparently be case sensitive due to WordPress caching. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18210 for more info.

Reference: [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) for more info

Comment: Aren't those lines of code identical?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook ya, sorry, stinking cut and past. I have edited and updated.